# How to update a sequence using Scala map method?

Tags: scala

I have the following sequence where I am updating every element of the pair by adding 1 by using a for-loop: ​

```scala
points: Seq[Point] = Seq((ax,ay), (bx,by), (cx,cy))
for (point <- points)
{
  ​val update = Point(point.x + 1, point.y + 1)
}
```

However, I want to use the map method to update my elements in the following way:

```scala
val update = points.map(x => (x._1 + 1, x._2 + 1))
```

But it's showing me the following error:

[image]

[image]

**So how can I then update my sequence using Scala map method and get rid of this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should write:

```
val update: Seq[Point] = points.map(point => Point(point.x + 1, point.y + 1))
```

As you done in the foor loop.